# How do you use map-reduce in scala dataframes when u have 2 fields and second field should be split?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, mapreduce, databricks

I have review_ratingremoved , which is of type [review_id, text] ,
i want to do a map-reduce function where i give out (review_id, word) as mapper output. But, i have to split my text into words and output all those words with associated review_id

Scala code:

```
val reviews = spark.read.option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").csv(review_path)

val review_ratingremoved = review_afterstep1.select("review_id","text")

val reviewmap = review_ratingremoved.map(_.map(_._2.split(" ")))

// not working showing this error:
//notebook:23: error: value map is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Row
//val reviewmap = review_ratingremoved.map(_.map(_._2.split(" ")))
```

Please help me figure this out. Thanks.

Comment: This is spark, not map-reduce

Comment: I am going to to do a reduce operation where i group by review_id, but i am not able to map it properly

Comment: Sounds like you got it all mixed up. `map` and `reduce` in Spark are just methods whereas MapReduce is an algorithm. Spark doesn't have mappers and reducers.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do the below:

```
review_ratingremoved .selectExpr("review_id", "split(text, ' ') as text_words")
```